# How to access nested data interface in React TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-native

In React TypeScript, what is the appropriate way to access data in a nested interface like the one below?

```
export interface School {
  prices: Array<{
    state: {
      response_header?: {
        school_type_opportunities?: Array<{ benefit_type_opportunity?: string }>;
        school_alternative_products?: Array<{
          school_alternative_cost_share_incentive?: string;
          school_alternative_description?: string;
          school_alternative_id?: string;
          school_attendance_required?: Array<{
            school_attendance_location?: string;
            school_attendance_blabla?: string;
            school_attendance_blabla2?: string;
          }>;
        }>;
```

I want to get access to:

- `school_type_opportunities`
- `school_alternative_description`
- `school_attendance_location`

Comment: I'd suggest reading e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide. You're going to get nowhere in TS and React if you don't know basic JS.

Comment: @jonrsharpe good point as i am coming from a python background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript is merely type-safe JavaScript, i.e. you'd practise the same methodologies and find e.g.

```js
const schoolTypeOportunities =
  School.prices[x].state.response_header.school_type_opportunities;
```

As `prices` is of type `Array` here (and depending on your application) you'd need to know which index is relevant and change `x`. Alternatively, if multiple, you can might find `map`, `filter`, or `reduce` convenient to extract your wanted items.